# XmlReader Parsing Error

Tags: vb.net, silverlight, xml-parsing, xmlreader

My XML generated is as follows:

```
<helpers>
         <person>
                 <latitude>17.123</latitude>
                 <longitude>83.322</longitude>
         </person>
         <person>
                 <latitude>17.123</latitude>
                 <longitude>83.322</longitude>
         </person>
</helpers>
```

I receive XML as response after POST to webpage. My VB.net code is as follows:

```
Using reader = XmlReader.Create(New StringReader(e.Result.ToString()))
        While reader.Read()
            If reader.NodeType = XmlNodeType.Element And reader.Name = "person" Then
                ParseAuthor(reader)
            End If
        End While
End Using

Sub ParseAuthor(ByVal MyReader As XmlReader)
    Dim lat, lng As String
    MyReader.ReadToFollowing("latitude")
    lat = MyReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
    MyReader.ReadToFollowing("longitude")
    lng = MyReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
    mapCenter = New GeoCoordinate(CType(lat, Double), CType(lng, Double))
    Dim position = PositionOrigin.Center
    imgLayer.AddChild(imgPinMembers, mapCenter, position)
End Sub
```

I am getting an error at

```
MyReader.ReadToFollowing("latitude")
```

and it says

> *The ReadElementContentAsString method is not supported on node type None.*

Can somebody point out the bug? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the correct way:

```
MyReader.ReadToDescendant("latitude")
lat = MyReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
MyReader.MoveToContent()
lng = MyReader.ReadElementContentAsString()
mapCenter = New GeoCoordinate(CType(lat, Double), CType(lng, Double))
Dim position = PositionOrigin.Center
imgLayer.AddChild(imgPinMembers(i), mapCenter, position)
MyReader.MoveToElement()
```

This executes without errors.